# Two pushurl failed with `magit-push-current-to-upstream`

Tags: magit

I have two `pushurl`s, say `owner1` and `owner2`, set to a remote.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/owner1/repo (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/owner1/repo (push)
origin  https://github.com/owner2/repo (push)
```

`git push origin` from command line works just fine, meaning `git` pushes changes to both remotes.

But, this seting fails with Magit.  How can I push to the remote with Magit?

Here is the copy from `magit-process` buffer

```
Pushing to https://github.com/owner1/repo
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 993 bytes | 993.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
POST git-receive-pack (1166 bytes)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (6/6), completed with 5 local objects.        
To https://github.com/owner1/repo
   67c5f50..7dfe966  main -> main
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main'
Pushing to https://github.com/owner2/repo
To https://github.com/owner2/repo
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (stale info)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/owner2/repo'
```

Comment: Which remote would you expect `git push origin` to push to?

Comment: @ChrisClark Both.